# Smart Paging Clean url redirects to Queried strings automatically

Tags: paging

I just use [Smart Paging](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_paging) module and it works great. Except one thing, when I click on next link, next page clean url is automatically redirected to queried string url.

Like `xyz.com/some-url.html/p/0/1 to xyz.com/some-url.html?page=0%2C1`

I'm not able to figure out the reason for this.

Can you please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with Global Redirect Module. Patch here https://www.drupal.org/node/1843500#comment-7535655 works, testing it on development site for now.